# What is the difference between 4GL and DSL?

Tags: terminology, dsl, 4gl

What is the difference between 4GL and DSL? Both seem to target a specific domain, but is it safe to say that 4GL is business oriented, while DSLs target any possible domain?

Comment: Did you mean 4G and DSL? instead of 4GL and DSL?

Comment: @Ozair Kafray most certainly not:) DSL - Domain Specific Language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth-generation_programming_language:

> A fourth-generation programming
>   language (1970s-1990) (abbreviated
>   4GL) is a programming language or
>   programming environment designed with
>   a specific purpose in mind, such as
>   the development of commercial business
>   software. In the history of
>   computer science, the 4GL followed the
>   3GL in an upward trend toward higher
>   abstraction and statement power. The
>   4GL was followed by efforts to define
>   and use a 5GL.
>
> **Fourth-generation languages have often been compared to domain-specific
>   programming languages (DSLs). Some
>   researchers state that 4GLs are a
>   subset of DSLs. Given the persistence
>   of assembly language even now
>   in advanced development environments
>   (MS Studio), one expects that a system
>   ought to be a mixture of all the
>   generations, with only very limited
>   use of the first.**

Also see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language

Answer (score 0):

4GLs are a subset of DSLs. DSLs can also include languages for a specific audience (like LOGO), not only specific uses. 4GLs are geared towards specific usage (Math, buisnes logic, etc.)

see http://homepages.cwi.nl/~arie/papers/dslbib/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4GL